# setIntervalがchromeだと正常に動作しない

Tags: html

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.test').fadeOut(500,function(){$(this).fadeIn(500)});
},2000);
```

クラス名にtestを指定したテキストを点滅させたいです。
IEでは点滅し続けるのだが、chromeだと一回点滅した後、点滅しなくなります。
2000ミリ秒を指定しているのですが、1000ミリ秒にするとchromeでも正常に動作します。
2000ミリ秒を指定する場合はどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

私の環境は以下ですが、2000ミリ秒指定でも動作しているようです。

```
chromeバージョン: 67.0.3396.99（Official Build） （64 ビット）
```

以下のコードは @html さんの chrome環境で動作するでしょうか?
また、動作しない時に、コンソールにエラーメッセージは出ていないでしょうか?

```js
setInterval(function() {
    $('.test').fadeOut(500,function(){$(this).fadeIn(500)});
},2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="test">hoge</p>
```